# When label tag should be used over span/dev tags in html form?

Tags: css, label, html

When label tag should be used over span or dev  in form?

Example:

**option1-span:**

```
<form action="">
<span>Name:</span><input type="text">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**option2-label:**

```
<form action="">
<label>Name:</label><input type="text">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**option3-div:**

```
<form action="">
<div style="display:inline;">Name:</div><input type="text">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what label tags are for:

```
<form action="">
<label for="txt">Name:</label><input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then clicking on the label will focus on the input element.

Answer (score 4):

The label tag is primarily used along with the for attribute.  This aids in web accessibility of forms.  For example

```
<form>
<label for="firstName">First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" value=""/>
</form>
```

By using the for tag, we can essentially associate the text "First Name:" with the input field having the name = "firstName".

Aside from that it has other attributes allowed but the span is more regularly used for styling markup.